# how can i make sure the email and confirm email input match using html/java

Tags: javascript, html, validation, email, confirm

im new here so take it easy on me please.

currently on shopify form i have edited the registration so that it asks for email and then also a confirm email box. how can i make sure that both boxes are matching before customer submits the form, if not matching it want it to state "email address's don't match". I believe this would be through javascript but not sure.

this how my code looks for the 2 boxes.

```
    <div class="Form__Item">
      <input type="email" class="Form__Input" name="customer[email]" aria-label="{{ 'customer.register.email' | t }}" placeholder="{{ 'customer.register.email' | t }}" required="required">
      <label class="Form__FloatingLabel">{{ 'customer.register.email' | t }}</label>
    </div>

   <div class="Form__Item">
      <input type="email" class="Form__Input" name="customer[confirm_email]" aria-label="{{ 'customer.register.confirm_email' | t }}" placeholder="{{ 'customer.register.confirm_email' | t }}" required="required">
      <label class="Form__FloatingLabel">{{ 'customer.register.confirm_email' | t }}</label>
    </div>
  
    <div class="Form__Item">
      <input type="password" class="Form__Input" name="customer[password]" aria-label="{{ 'customer.register.password' | t }}" placeholder="{{ 'customer.register.password' | t }}" required="required">
      <label class="Form__FloatingLabel">{{ 'customer.register.password' | t }}</label>
    </div>
  
    
    <button type="submit" class="Form__Submit Button Button--primary Button--full">{{ 'customer.register.submit' | t }}</button>
  {%- endform -%}
</div>
```

thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Java != Javascript

Answer (score 0):

with **HTML5** you can check common validation on inputs like **Required, minLenght, MaxLength**,... even pattern for input data
 for this case you have to use javascript and better use **JQuery** 
example:

```
<input type="text" id="id1" />
<input type="text" id="id2" />

$('input').blur(function() {
if ($('#id1').attr('value') == $('#id2').attr('value')) {
alert('Same Value');
return false;
} else { return true; }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply compare the values of both input fields and verify if both fields have the same value.

```js
function validate(){
  let i1 = document.querySelector("#i1").value;
  let i2 = document.querySelector("#i2").value;
  if(i1 === i2){
    alert("Values matched");
  }else{
    alert("Values not matching");
  }

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="i1">
<input type="text" id="i2">
<button onclick="validate()">Submit</button>
```